# Update / Add new record does not work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using this tutorial(http://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/3064-basic-php-system-view-edit-add-delete-records-with-mysqli/) and I followed every step required in order to create new records into the database but I cannot get update/edit to successfully update my database. I know that the code is not for html5 but I will fix that later. Additionally, retrieve & delete works.

What am I doing wrong? Why is it not working? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also my table is structured like this,

```
Table: supplyDetails
Columns:
id int(11) AI PK
localAuthority varchar(50)
supplyRef varchar(50)
supplyName varchar(50)
estimatedDailyWater varchar(10)
numberOfConsumers varchar(45)
dateOfAssessment date
mitigatedRating varchar(2)
finalRating varchar(2)
```

Here is my records.php

```
<?php
/*
Allows the user to both create new records and edit existing records
*/

// connect to the database
include("connect-db.php");

// creates the new/edit record form
// since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable
function renderForm($localauth = '', $supref = '', $supname = '',  $waterusage = '', $numofconsum = '',  $dateofassess = '',  $mitrating = '',  $frating = '', $error = '', $id = '') {
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>
<?php
if ($id != '') {
  echo "Edit Record";
  } else {
    echo "New Record";
  }
?>
</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
  <?php
    if ($id != '') {
      echo "Edit Record";
      } else {
        echo "New Record";
      }
  ?>
</h1>

<?php
  if ($error != '') {
    echo "<div style='padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red'>" . $error
    . "</div>";
  }
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<div>
<?php
  if ($id != '') {
?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<p>ID: <?php echo $id; ?></p>
<?php } ?>

<label>Local Authority: *</label>
<input type="text" name="localAuthority" value="<?php echo $localauth; ?>"/>
<br/>

<label>Supply Reference: *</label>
<input type="text" name="supplyRef" value="<?php echo $supref; ?>"/>
<br/>

<label>Supply Name: *</label>
<input type="text" name="supplyName" value="<?php echo $supname; ?>"/>
<br/>

<label>Estimated Daily Water Usage: *</label>
<input type="text" name="estimatedDailyWater" value="<?php echo $waterusage; ?>"/>
<br/>

<label>Number of Consumers: *</label>
<input type="text" name="numberOfConsumers" value="<?php echo $numofconsum; ?>"/>
<br/>

<label>Date of Assessment: *</label>
<input type="date" name="dateOfAssessment" value="<?php echo $dateofassess; ?>"/>
<br/>

<label>Mitigated Rating: *</label>
<input type="text" name="mitigatedRating" value="<?php echo $mitrating; ?>"/>
<br/>

<label>Final Rating: *</label>
<input type="text" name="finalRating" value="<?php echo $frating; ?>"/>

<p>* required</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
}

/*

EDIT RECORD

*/
// if the 'id' variable is set in the URL, we know that we need to edit a record
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
// if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// make sure the 'id' in the URL is valid
if (is_numeric($_POST['id'])) {
// get variables from the URL/form
$id = $_POST['id'];
$localAuthority = htmlentities($_POST['localAuthority'], ENT_QUOTES);
$supplyRef = htmlentities($_POST['supplyRef'], ENT_QUOTES);
$supplyName = htmlentities($_POST['supplyName'], ENT_QUOTES);
$estimatedDailyWater = htmlentities($_POST['estimatedDailyWater'], ENT_QUOTES);
$numberOfConsumers = htmlentities($_POST['numberOfConsumers'], ENT_QUOTES);
$dateOfAssessment = htmlentities($_POST['dateOfAssessment'], ENT_QUOTES);
$mitigatedRating = htmlentities($_POST['mitigatedRating'], ENT_QUOTES);
$finalRating = htmlentities($_POST['finalRating'], ENT_QUOTES);

// check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
if ($localAuthority == '' || $supplyRef == ''  || $supplyName == ''  || $estimatedDailyWater == '' || $numberOfConsumers == ''  || $dateOfAssessment == ''  || $mitigatedRating == ''  || $finalRating == '') {
// if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
renderForm($localAuthority, $supplyRef, $supplyName, $estimatedDailyWater, $numberOfConsumers, $dateOfAssessment, $mitigatedRating, $finalRating, $error, $id);
} else {
// if everything is fine, update the record in the database
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE supplyDetails SET localAuthority = ?, supplyRef = ?, supplyName = ?, estimatedDailyWater = ?, numberOfConsumers = ?, dateOfAssessment = ?, mitigatedRating = ?, finalRating = ? WHERE id=?")) {
$stmt->bind_param("sssssdssi", $localAuthority, $supplyRef, $supplyName, $estimatedDailyWater, $numberOfConsumers, $dateOfAssessment, $mitigatedRating, $finalRating, $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
// show an error message if the query has an error
else {
  echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
}

// redirect the user once the form is updated
header("Location: view.php");
}
}
// if the 'id' variable is not valid, show an error message
else {
  echo "Error!";
}
}
// if the form hasn't been submitted yet, get the info from the database and show the form
else {
// make sure the 'id' value is valid
if (is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0) {
// get 'id' from URL
$id = $_GET['id'];

// get the recod from the database
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM supplyDetails WHERE id=?")) {
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($id, $localAuthority, $supplyRef, $supplyName, $estimatedDailyWater, $numberOfConsumers, $dateOfAssessment, $mitigatedRating, $finalRating);
$stmt->fetch();

// show the form
renderForm($localAuthority, $supplyRef, $supplyName, $estimatedDailyWater, $numberOfConsumers, $dateOfAssessment, $mitigatedRating, $finalRating, NULL, $id);

$stmt->close();
}
// show an error if the query has an error
else {
echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement";
}
}
// if the 'id' value is not valid, redirect the user back to the view.php page
else {
header("Location: view.php");
}
}
}


/*

NEW RECORD

*/
// if the 'id' variable is not set in the URL, we must be creating a new record
else {
// if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// get the form data
$localAuthority = htmlentities($_POST['localAuthority'], ENT_QUOTES);
$supplyRef = htmlentities($_POST['supplyRef'], ENT_QUOTES);
$supplyName = htmlentities($_POST['supplyName'], ENT_QUOTES);
$estimatedDailyWater = htmlentities($_POST['estimatedDailyWater'], ENT_QUOTES);
$numberOfConsumers = htmlentities($_POST['numberOfConsumers'], ENT_QUOTES);
$dateOfAssessment = htmlentities($_POST['dateOfAssessment'], ENT_QUOTES);
$mitigatedRating = htmlentities($_POST['mitigatedRating'], ENT_QUOTES);
$finalRating = htmlentities($_POST['finalRating'], ENT_QUOTES);

// check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
if ($localAuthority == '' || $supplyRef == '' || $supplyName == '' || $estimatedDailyWater == '' || $numberOfConsumers == '' || $dateOfAssessment == '' || $mitigatedRating == '' || $finalRating == '') {
// if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
renderForm($localAuthority, $supplyRef, $supplyName, $estimatedDailyWater, $numberOfConsumers, $dateOfAssessment, $mitigatedRating, $finalRating, $error);
} else {
// insert the new record into the database
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT supplyDetails (localAuthority, supplyRef, supplyName, estimatedDailyWater, numberOfConsumers, dateOfAssessment, mitigatedRating, finalRating)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
$stmt->bind_param("sssssdss", $localAuthority, $supplyRef, $supplyName, $estimatedDailyWater, $numberOfConsumers, $dateOfAssessment, $mitigatedRating, $finalRating);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
// show an error if the query has an error
else {
echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
}

// redirec the user
header("Location: view.php");
}

}
// if the form hasn't been submitted yet, show the form
else {
renderForm();
}
}

// close the mysqli connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

view.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>View Records</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>

<h1>View Records</h1>

<p><b>View All</b> | <a href="view-paginated.php">View Paginated</a></p>

<?php
// connect to the database
include('connect-db.php');

// get the records from the database
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM supplyDetails ORDER BY id"))
{
// display records if there are records to display
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
// display records in a table
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";

// set table headers
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>ID</th>";
echo "<th>Local Authority</th>";
echo "<th>Supply Reference</th>";
echo "<th>Supply Name</th>";
echo "<th>Estimated Daily Water Usage</th>";
echo "<th>Number of Consumers</th>";
echo "<th>Date of Assessment</th>";
echo "<th>Mitigated Rating</th>";
echo "<th>Final Rating</th>";
echo "<th></th><th></th></tr>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
// set up a row for each record
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row->id . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->localAuthority . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->supplyRef . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->supplyName . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->estimatedDailyWater . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->numberOfConsumers . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->dateOfAssessment . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->mitigatedRating . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->finalRating . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='records.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Edit</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Delete</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
}
// if there are no records in the database, display an alert message
else
{
echo "No results to display!";
}
}
// show an error if there is an issue with the database query
else
{
echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
}

// close database connection
$mysqli->close();

?>

<a href="records.php">Add New Record</a>
</body>
</html>
```

connect-db.php

```
<?php

// server info
$server = 'localhost:3306';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '*****';
$db = 'test';

// connect to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

// show errors (remove this line if on a live site)
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);

?>
```

**SOLUTION** for future references.

OK, I managed to come up with an answer. I implemented a proper error handler, thanks to the suggestions above, into my connect-db.php file

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL) ;
try {
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

// show errors (remove this line if on a live site)

} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

After fiddling around with editing a record, I was receiving an error regarding the date, so I changed the date type in my mysql table and from date -> varchar (30). (30 may be a lot for a date but meh)

Then I changed my code a bit to reflect those changes,

```
$dateOfAssessment = htmlentities($_POST['dateOfAssessment'], ENT_QUOTES);
$displaydate = date("D d M Y", strtotime($dateOfAssessment));
```

And also changed the `$stmt` to

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE supplyDetails SET localAuthority = ?, supplyRef = ?, supplyName = ?, estimatedDailyWater = ?, numberOfConsumers = ?, dateOfAssessment = ?, mitigatedRating = ?, finalRating = ? WHERE id=?")) {
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssi", $localAuthority, $supplyRef, $supplyName, $estimatedDailyWater, $numberOfConsumers, $displaydate, $mitigatedRating, $finalRating, $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
```

And the output is something like this:

```
Sat 06 Aug 2016
```

Thanks everyone who had the time to reply.

Comment: Any error messages, or errors in the log?

Comment: There aren't any errors

Comment: Here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php - http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and apply that to your code, see if anything comes of it.

Comment: also, if your column lengths aren't long enough, MySQL will actually fail ***silently.*** You also need to check if your connection failed. That tutorial should have included to add `exit;` after each header also.

Comment: given no more interaction in light of comments given, you have been given an answer below. Ask them now. If you know how to ping someone, you can. I have left the question.

Comment: Can you suggest where I can add the error handling suggested above?

Comment: Like at the top of my php file that you can see with the example for `mysqli` Registration off my profile page

Comment: insert query would be `INSERT into supplyDetails`

Comment: I would like to say I figured out the solution, which is provided below. Thanks everyone. In 2 days I will be able to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I managed to come up with an answer. I implemented a proper error handler, thanks to the suggestions above, into my connect-db.php file

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL) ;
try {
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

// show errors (remove this line if on a live site)

} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

After fiddling around with editing a record, I was receiving an error regarding the date, so I changed the date type in my mysql table and from date -> varchar (30). (30 may be a lot for a date but meh)

Then I changed my code a bit to reflect those changes,

```
$dateOfAssessment = htmlentities($_POST['dateOfAssessment'], ENT_QUOTES);
$displaydate = date("D d M Y", strtotime($dateOfAssessment));
```

And also changed the `$stmt` to

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE supplyDetails SET localAuthority = ?, supplyRef = ?, supplyName = ?, estimatedDailyWater = ?, numberOfConsumers = ?, dateOfAssessment = ?, mitigatedRating = ?, finalRating = ? WHERE id=?")) {
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssi", $localAuthority, $supplyRef, $supplyName, $estimatedDailyWater, $numberOfConsumers, $displaydate, $mitigatedRating, $finalRating, $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
```

And the output is something like this:

```
Sat 06 Aug 2016
```

Thanks everyone who had the time to reply.